# Converting PDF to Image without non-python dependencies

Tags: python, pdf, pyinstaller, wand

I want to create an exe that can be deployed onto other computers. The program needs to be able to read pdf's and turn them into images, but I don't want other users to have to download dependencies.

My understanding is that py2image and wand both require external dependencies that, if you convert to a exe, other users would also need to download the dependencies themselves.

Are there other options available/ workarounds ?

Comment: Are you trying to create a program to convert PDF to image?
If yes what do you mean by "not using python dependencies"?

Comment: That would be part of the program, yes. I don't want to use things like imagemagick or poppler, as then when I deploy the program as an exe other users would need to install those programs.

Comment: Creating an executable from a working py script is totally different from Not using external dependencies for your script. I think you have to use an external package to handle the job for you and then you can simply pack it to a single executable to run without any dependencies. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. If I were to download/use imagemagick, do you know how I could include that into the executable with pyinstaller/other methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it took me a while to handle this, but I think it worth it.
You need to do all steps carefully to make it work.

1. Install [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) with `pip install pdf2image`.
2. Get [poppler](https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) windows binaries.
3. Create a new directory like `myproject`.
4. Create a script `converter.py` inside `myproject` and add below code.
5. Create another directory inside `myproject` and name it `poppler`.
6. Copy all files in the binary folder of downloaded poppler into `poppler` directory. Try to test `pdfimages.exe` if it is working.
7. Use `pyinstaller converter.py -F --add-data "./poppler/*;./poppler" --noupx`
8. Your executable is now ready. Run it like `converter.exe myfile.pdf`. Results would be created inside the `output` directory next to the executable.
9. Now your standalone **PDF2IMAGE** converter app is ready!

`converter.py`:

```
import sys
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_path


def current_path(dir_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, dir_path)
    return os.path.join(".", dir_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("PASS your PDF file: \"converter.exe myfile.pdf\"")
        input()
        sys.exit(0)
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + \
        os.pathsep.join([current_path("poppler")])

    if not os.path.isdir("./output"):
        os.makedirs("output")
    images = convert_from_path(sys.argv[-1], 500)
    for image, i in zip(images, (range(len(images)))):
        image.save('./output/out{}.png'.format(i), 'PNG')
```

**PS:** If you like it, you can add a GUI and add more settings for `pdf2images`.

Comment: You're amazing, thank you for your help. This is going to be part of a broader application, and I haven't yet started on this part of the app, but when I get there I will test this out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running in conda environment and I'm totally lost how I should `--add-data` conda-installed poppler to the command.

Comment: This requires poppler, and the question explicitly asks for non-python dependencies, so I am not sure why this answer is here.

Comment: @EmiliaApostolova Read the comments on the question if you are not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a solution, apparently one needs a PDF renderer no matter what. The most lightweight solution is https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html. It is still a python binding for a PDF renderer (https://www.mupdf.com/), but you can install it, including its dependency, by:

```
pip install PyMuPDF
```

No need to install poppler or imagemagick.

Then you can convert a pdf to images as follows:

```
import fitz  

doc = fitz.open(stream=your_pdf_file_stream, filetype="pdf")  
for idx, page in enumerate(doc):  
    pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=600) 
    the_page_bytes=pix.pil_tobytes(format="PNG")
    with open("page-%s.png"%idx, "wb") as outf:
        outf.write(the_page_bytes)
```

Unfortunately, mupdf has a copyleft license, so keep that in mind.

Comment: ? Not sure what you mean, it has a GNU license (apache is not a copyleft license anyway), and also you don't need to install any exes if you are using the python wheels, via "pip install PyMuPDF". Per the documentation: Python wheels exist for Windows (32bit and 64bit), Linux (64bit, Intel and ARM) and Mac OSX (64bit, Intel only).

Comment: The fact that this does not need anything besides an entry in `requirements.txt` makes this the best answer by far. No one wants to mess with installing all kinds of third-party software manually and then fiddling with search paths just to get a script going.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem while trying to make .exe file with pyqt5 and pdf2file modules, using pyinstaller.
If you need to add GUI created in PyQt5, do not add --windowed in pyinstaller command. That was ruining my work for 2days