How to convert multi-page PDF file to image without using pdf2Image?
I am trying to use pdf2image to convert a multi-page PDF to since image variable like it is done in Textractor code so that I can use it in LazyDocument:
import pdf2image
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
import boto3
from textractcaller import call_textract, OutputConfig
from textractcaller.t_call import Textract_Call_Mode, Textract_API, get_full_json


file_source = 's3://mybucket/my/path/to/file.pdf'
bucket = 'mybucket'
key = 'my/path/to/file.pdf'

session = boto3.session.Session(region_name= 'us-east-1')
textract_client = session.client("textract", region_name= 'us-east-1')

output_config = OutputConfig(s3_bucket=bucket, s3_prefix=key)
response = call_textract(
            input_document=file_source,
            ouptput_config = output_config,
            features=[TextractFeatures.FORMS, TextractFeatures.TABLES, TextractFeatures.SIGNATURES, TextractFeatures.LAYOUT],
            return_job_id=True,
            force_async_api=True,
            call_mode=Textract_Call_Mode.FORCE_ASYNC,
            boto3_textract_client= textract_client,
            job_done_polling_interval=1,
        )

s3_client = session.client("s3")

file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key).get("Body").read()
images = convert_from_bytes(bytearray(file_obj))

LazyDoc = LazyDocument(
        response["JobId"],
        Textract_API.ANALYZE,
        textract_client= textract_client,
        images=images,
        output_config=output_config,
    )

Although the package installs properly when using pip install pdf2image. I am getting the error:
PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I have seen solutions that say to download the necessay file and specify the poppler_path. However, due to permission issues I am not allowed do upload any files from online into the required space. Is there another way to get the images variable without using pdf2image?

You'll need something that is able to render PDFs into images, and I doubt there is a pure-Python solution for that, since PDFs are complex beasts.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70453675/5003756

Here is a solution with PyMuPDF:
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")
for page in doc:
    pix = page.get_pixmap(dpi=150)  # pymupdf's internal image format, at DPI=150
    pix.save("page-%i.png" % page.number)  # save page as PNG

To not outputting to file but returning a bytes object in PNG format use pix.tobytes("png") as appropriate. Other image formats (JPEG) are available too.
Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.
